# PHP Strom setting to draw line before function declaration

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm using PHP Storm in my work. And there was one feature that made code more readable. But it gone somewhere and I can't bring it back. It lookde like

[image: phpstorm line]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance 
and find checkbox `Show method separators`

[image: show-method-separators]